# What does this SQL query do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble understanding what this query accomplishes:

```
DECLARE @CatalogID int
INSERT [Catalog] ([Name])
SELECT @Catalog WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Name] FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Name] = @Catalog)
SELECT @CatalogID = ID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Name] = @Catalog
```

The schema comprises of five tables catalogue, data entry, dataentryversion, tags, users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're inserting a record if it doesn't already exist and then returning the ID of the record that was either inserted, or was already there.

I've added comments to the code below:

```
DECLARE @CatalogID int --Create a variable to hold the Catalog id 
INSERT [Catalog] ([Name]) --Inserting into the catalog table
SELECT @Catalog --The SELECT will only return a value if a matching record does not exist
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Name] FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Name] = @Catalog) 

SELECT @CatalogID = ID FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Name] = @Catalog --Returns the ID of the catalog record
```

For what it's worth, it is possible to write this query the other way around, i.e. selecting the matching record out of `catalog` and if nothing is returned then performing the insert but this approach is superior in that it is not vulnerable to a 'race condition' where two processes may be trying to insert the same record at the same time.

Comment: yaeh why not !!! , i would love to but how do you mark a response as a correct answer ??  pardon me , but i am kind a new to this tech-forum-thing  , there was a button below , with the text asking " was this post helpful to you" , i have already clicked it , !!!????